# Getting "Request failed with status code 401" error when trying to create a playlist in Spotify using their API

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, spotify

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    await axios.post(arg.url,
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${SPYauthToken}`
            },
            params: {name: "playlist"},

        }
    )
```

I have already previously provided access to all the necessary scopes and gotten a corresponding authentication token, yet when I try to create a playlist with the code I provided, I get an error saying "Request failed with status code 401".

Nor does it work when I tried creating a playlist in the Spotify's own API site here: https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlists/ After clicking "try it" using their own example, nothing happens and no playlist is created for me.

Am I doing something royally wrong, or is it something that Spotify has to sort out?

Thanks!

Comment: you're missing quotes on Authorization header, anyway did you tried if curl works?

Comment: Hi, it did work using curl. So it's definitely something on my end. Regardless adding quotes didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I fixed it using fetch. For some reason Axios refuses to work with POST requests

Comment: please have a look to my answer maybe it solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try it but you can do following

```
    // request data object
    const data = {
        name: "playlist"
    };

    // set the headers
    const config = {
       headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${SPYauthToken}`
        }
    };

await axios.post(arg.url, data, config);
// maybe you need to stringify data so
await axios.post(arg.url, JSON.stringify(data), config);
```

Comment: This solution does work as well, in addition to using fetch (no need to stringify) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    await axios.post(arg.url,
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${SPYauthToken}`
            },
            params: {name: "playlist"},

        }
    )
```

You didn't used Quotes around Authorization

Comment: I've never used them when not using dashes in the name and it has worked. Anyway, adding them didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using fetch:

```
    const data = { name: 'playlist' };

    fetch(arg.url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${SPYauthToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
```

Works flawlessly. Axios doesn't seem to work using POST, at least not as expected, so I'll probably stop using it.

Thanks to everybody who answered.